# VBA how to loop through a column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I know start cell, and I need to go down through the column. And I need to exit cycle when the next cell is empty. How to do it in VBA code?

Thanks for replies

Comment: While this is marked as answered what do you want to do with the column once the range is defined?

Comment: I am working with Cognos TM1, and need to get comments on cells from OLAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about;

```
'//get a range from anchor cell (a1) to the 1st empty cell in the same column;
dim r As Range, cell as Range
set r = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))

'//loop it
for Each cell In r
    msgbox cell.Value
next
```

Comment: 1) I would not use cell as a variable name. Call it myCell.  
2) You need to `DIM myCell as Range`

Comment: Added a dim, I left cell as is, it isn't a reserved word and isn't used anywhere as a class name in the xl object model (although Cells is)

Comment: @Alex: you're are probably right for Cell. I am too cautious :-/

Answer (score 2):

I adjusted AlexK's answer:

```
dim c As Range

'//loop it
for Each c In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    msgbox c.Value
next
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, everything cell-based can be done with ranges, using offsets to return the value you are looking for:

```
Dim Anchor as Range

Set Anchor = Range("A1")

i = 0
Do 
  ' Cell in column is Anchor.Offset(0, i)
  ' i.e., Anchor.Offset(0, 0) = A1
  '       Anchor.Offset(0, 1) = B1
  '       Anchor.Offset(0, ") = C1
  '       etc.

  ' Do whatever you like with this, here!

  i = i + 1
Loop Until Anchor.Offset(0, i) = ""
```